# select 1 from table, select 2 from table, select 3 from table e.t.c

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Is this all query same? I can't see any difference in result, It just change the number in table row according to our selection. but, why we always use 1. Does it has some technical meaning and advantages?

Comment: "why we always use 1" - do we? I, personally, do not. So who are this "we" who "always use 1"?

Comment: I see generally developer use 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query like `SELECT <Something> FROM Tablename` selects `something` per row of `tablename`.
Now if this `something` is not a column of table, and we just want to avoid computation on table, we use a number like `1` or `2` or anything that can be returned per row without calculation. They are all the same.
Even something like

```
SELECT 'I am doing good' FROM tablename
```

Some smart developers choose to return a scalar value which can be useful for other parts of query like say

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Issue_Log) 
BEGIN
   PRINT 'HAVE MORE WORK'
END
```

In the above example we are simply checking if there are any rows in `Issue_Log` table. We simply return 1 from select query. If there were no rows, we'd not get any number of 1 as result and there fore `IF EXISTS(NULL)` is evaluated as false.

Welcome to world of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that the number you specify will be returned for as many times as there are rows in the table. The number of rows is same but the value returned is what you specify in the SELECT statement

Comment: Yes exactly. But, I usually see all developer prefer 1 . Does it take more time or any to use other number like 100,20000, 400000000. e.t.c

Comment: You edited the post. In exists it does not matter. You can use anthing

Answer (score 0):

Yes all are same,if you mean something like

```
 SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
          WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE conditions...)
```

it's just a random value. Even you can use `*,NULL`..etc like

```
 SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
           WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE conditions...)
```